# How to pass "Month" and "Year" Only parameter from datetimepicker to crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Good morning, i am struggling with this Crystal report problem, i have the formula on my report :

```
cstr(monthname(month({kwitansi1.tgl_kwitansi})))+" - " +cstr(year({kwitansi1.tgl_kwitansi}),0)
```

It is working and showing the data that i want, which is like this :

```
May-2015          $1000
June-2015         $600
July-2015         $250
August-2015       $1500
```

And i have 2 parameter, "?month1" and "?Month2", when i preview it say the field name is not known.

Those parameters is for datetimepicker1 and datetimepicker2.
So basically i want to show, for example:
if i click on datetimepicker1 then fill it with some random date but Month is May-2015 and then i click datetimepicker2 fill it with random date too but Month is August-2015, and then i click "print" button, the crystal report should show those data above that i want.

I am using this on vb.form to pass the parameters to Crystal Report.

```
 objrepdoc = New CRLaporanPendapatanPerbulan
        objrepdoc.SetParameterValue("month1", Format(FormCetakLaporanPendapatan.datetimepicker1.Value, "MMMM-YYYY"))
        objrepdoc.SetParameterValue("month2", Format(FormCetakLaporanPendapatan.datetimepicker2.Value, "MMMM-YYYY"))
        objrepdoc.RecordSelectionFormula = "{kwitansi1.tgl_kwitansi} >= #" & Format(FormCetakLaporanPendapatan.datetimepicker1.Value, "MMMM-YYYY") & "# And {kwitansi1.tgl_kwitansi} <= #" & Format(FormCetakLaporanPendapatan.datetimepicker2.Value, "MMMM-YYYY") & "#"
```

I know those codes is wrong, :( because if i chose any month, the crystal report show all the data that has been saved on the `date` (kwitansi1.tgl_kwitansi) field. What i want is the CR is to show only specified data that VB.Form send using datetimepicker1 and datetimepicker2

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no one answer my question, i will answer this for reference of other people that have the same problem.

So, the easy part is actually:

- Make 2 parameters, first for the starting parameter and second for the ending parameter, basically we will make an "In between" code.
- After that, right click on the print area (everywhere) and click Report> selection formula > Record > The dialog showed up > copy-paste this `{tableA.date_table} in {?parameter1} to {?parameter2}`
- Save them

On the windows form use this:

- Make 2 datetimepicker
- Copy-paste this on form:

`Dim objrepdoc As New ReportDocument`

```
 `objrepdoc = New CrystalReport1
        objrepdoc.SetParameterValue("parameter1", Format(Form1.DTdate1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
        objrepdoc.SetParameterValue("parameter2", Format(Form1.DTdate2.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
        objrepdoc.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tableA.date_table} >= #" & Format(Form1.DTdate1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "# And {tableA.date_table} <= #" & Format(Form1.DTdate2.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "#"`
```

NOTE: The datetimepicker may show the date as well , you can modify it so that datetimepicker shows only month and Year.